# crunching multiple js files during development

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I'm writing a backbone.js app. I have multiple js, css and html template files. I also have a script to crunch them into a single file so it is faster to download. How should I work during development:

1. Add a listener to the file system and after every change compile the files so I can see it in a browser. This implies a 1-2 seconds overhead before I can see what I did, which is annoying for html fine-tuning.
2. Somehow browse using the multiple files during development and only crunch before going to production. This means I need to have a separate index.html for dev and prod.

What's your take?

Comment: I do have to wonder: What on earth is your script doing if it takes 1-2 seconds to compile? I've done this before, and the time never exceeded 1 second

Comment: the crunch itself is short. but the file system watcher has a slight delay before it calls the crunching script.

Comment: Then that's your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to combine and minify my JS, and in my index.html for my backbone apps, I simply have a code block like this:

```
   if (APP._dev === true) {
        // So on development, we load all the files individually
        $.when(
                // Utilities
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/util.js'),

                // Models
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/models/Timer.js'),
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/models/Section.js'),

                // Collections
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/collections/Timers.js'),
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/collections/Sections.js'),

                // Views
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/views/TitleView.js'),
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/views/BackgroundAudioView.js'),

                // Router
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/routers/APPRouter.js'),

                // Load in our templates file and add each template to a
                // proerty visible in our application scope
                $.get(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/templates/all.html',function(result){
                    var tmp = $('<div></div>').html(result);
                    $('script.template', tmp).each(function(){
                        APP._templates[this.id] = $(this).html();
                    });
                },'html'),

                // Here we create a new deferred object which we will bind
                // to JQuery's ready() event.
                $.Deferred(function (deferred) {

                    // DOM Ready. Invokes our APP.init() function.
                    $(deferred.resolve); // init
                })
        ).done(
                APP.init
        ).fail(
                function () { /* fail how you would like */ }
        );
    } else {
        $.when(
                // And on prod, we load a combined & minified JS file instead
                $.getScript(APP._rootDir + 'min/?g=js'),

                // Load in our templates file and add each template to a
                // proerty visible in our application scope
                $.get(APP._rootDir + 'app/js/templates/all.html',function(result){
                    var tmp = $('<div></div>').html(result);
                    $('script.template', tmp).each(function(){
                        APP._templates[this.id] = $(this).html();
                    });
                },'html'),

                // Here we create a new deferred object which we will bind
                // to JQuery's ready() event.
                $.Deferred(function (deferred) {

                    // DOM Ready. Invokes our APP.init() function.
                    $(deferred.resolve); // init
                })
        ).done(
                APP.init
        ).fail(
                function () { /* fail how you would like */ }
        );
    }
```

Then, in my groupsConfig in my Minify's `/min/` directory, I define my build array to match jQuery's deferred object load order:

```
return array(
    'js' => array(
        '//' . $rootDir . '/util.js',

        '//' . $rootDir . '/models/Timer.js',
        '//' . $rootDir . '/models/Section.js',

        '//' . $rootDir . '/collections/Timers.js',
        '//' . $rootDir . '/collections/Sections.js',

        '//' . $rootDir . '/views/TitleView.js',
        '//' . $rootDir . '/views/BackgroundAudioView.js',

        '//' . $rootDir . '/routers/APPRouter.js'
    ),
    'css' => array(),
);
```

It's probably not as DRY as it could be but it works and you can tweak it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a nightmare to work with combined and minified files using development. Two parallel index file would also be painful.

You are looking for [build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation). Write a build script which prepares your project for deployment. In your case, this would be to crunch all files and then modify your index file to only reference the combined file. Other tasks can include updating connection strings, uploading via FTP etc.

A simple bash script would do, but you can also go for [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/), [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) or any other build script. The key is repeatability. You should be able to do this using a simple command.

Edit: If you are going with Ant, look into `Exec`/`ReplaceRegexp` tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a html page with as many  tags as files I have, to develop phase.

When it has to go to production it can be crunched.

For next projects I recommend use requireJS who loads the files in the correct order under development and r.js can join every scripts in one file for production.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a file watcher program to do the update. The "Last Modified" field makes a file system watcher unnecessary.

Do the following when the user makes the request:

- After minifying everything, save a cached version of the result.
- Every time you load, check if the "Last Modified" field of any of the files is newer than the cache. If it is, re-minify everything, cache it, and return the newly cached version. Otherwise, just return the cached version. Simple and only runs when you need it.

Development is fast. Production is faster. Both use the same code.

Comment: thanks, for now I will go with what @AlienWebguy suggested since it is faster to implement,but I may switch to your suggestion later on

Answer (score 0):

I am using require.js and trying to compress all files with r.js but problem I found is they can compress .js .css files but not with .html files. I now have 50 templates and take 10 seconds to load them for the first time.